# async http call taking twice as long as it should

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am learning async and semaphore, I have made an endpoint using fastapi to test against. The fastapi end point is just a simple server side that takes a request with a sleep time in it and will sleep that long before returning the response. I run the fastapi via uvicorn for testing purpose but with 5 workers. this is for testing only, i understand fro production i should use gunicorn and nginx, but for the purposes of learning i am just using uvicorn

`uvicorn api_example:app --port 8008 --host cdsre.co.uk --workers 5`

**api_example.py**

```py
from time import sleep, time
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/sleeper")
async def sleeper(request: Request):
    request_data = await request.json()
    sleep_time = request_data['sleep_time']
    start = time()
    sleep(sleep_time)
    end = time()
    return Response(content=json.dumps({"slept for": end - start}))
```

client code on my local machine is trying to utilise async and semaphore to call 3 post requests in parallel. I have 6 requests, and sleep timer of 5 seconds. So expectation here is that it should take 10 seconds approx to process the 6 requests.

**async_example.py**

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time


async def get_http_response(session, url):
    async with semaphore:
        print("firing request...")
        start = time.time()
        async with session.post(url, json={"sleep_time": 5}) as resp:
            response = await resp.text()
            end = time.time()
            print(f"Client time: {end - start}, server time: {response}")
            return response


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for number in range(6):
            url = f'http://cdsre.co.uk:8008/sleeper'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_http_response(session, url)))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            pass
            # print(response)


semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(3)
start_time = time.time()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

However frequently the post request takes twice as long as it should. In this case with a sleep timer of 5 seconds some requests take 10 seconds.

```
firing request...
firing request...
firing request...
Client time: 5.137275695800781, server time: {"slept for": 5.005105018615723}
firing request...
Client time: 10.158655643463135, server time: {"slept for": 5.0042970180511475}
Client time: 10.158655643463135, server time: {"slept for": 5.001959800720215}
firing request...
firing request...
Client time: 5.055504560470581, server time: {"slept for": 5.005110025405884}
Client time: 5.056135654449463, server time: {"slept for": 5.005115509033203}
Client time: 5.107320070266724, server time: {"slept for": 5.005107402801514}
--- 15.271023750305176 seconds ---
```

sometimes its 3 times as slow, its always by a factor of my sleep time, which makes me think there is some sort of queuing happening or some sort of race condition I am missing,however i thought the whole purpose of the semaphore pattern was to avoid these race conditions such that my limiting to 3 requests at any one time is always going to be less than the works available on the server side (5 workers) so there should always be a working available server side to process it.

I also dont start time timing until inside the semaphore so I am not starting it early so it should only start the timer when its sending the request. Hopefully i am just missing something obvious. I have left the end point url up if anyone wants to try it. I would appreciate any help in solving this. Essentially i need to be able to write an async client that can send request in parallel up to a limit and be consistent in measureing the response time.

**Exmaple of some taking 3 times as long**

```
firing request...
firing request...
firing request...
Client time: 15.127191305160522, server time: {"slept for": 5.001192808151245}
firing request...
Client time: 15.127155303955078, server time: {"slept for": 5.005094766616821}
Client time: 15.127155303955078, server time: {"slept for": 5.005074977874756}
firing request...
firing request...
Client time: 5.053789854049683, server time: {"slept for": 5.005076169967651}
Client time: 5.100871801376343, server time: {"slept for": 5.005076885223389}
Client time: 10.107984781265259, server time: {"slept for": 5.005110502243042}
--- 25.236175775527954 seconds ---
```

Comment: You’re using `time.sleep`. This will block the thread. You want to use `await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)`.

Comment: yeah but i want the thread to block on the server end to simulate the app taking some time do something. What I dont get is that I have 5 workers available on the server side and only ever send at most 3 requests at the same time. So there should always be a worker free to pick up the request, sleep for that time then return the response. But sometimes that response time on the client side it 2 or 3 times slower, and its always by a factor of the sleep time, I.E if the sleep time is 5, its always 5, or 10 or 15, its never 7 or 12 etc. So i figure there must be something in the client side.

Comment: However, having taken your comment and applied it in my code the results are a lot more consistent . So what is the difference between time.sleep in a worker and await asyncio.sleep.......I was thinking that each worker would get a seperate request, so a sleep blocking that thread wouldnt affect the others.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer as its 100% solved my issue. any further explanation about why it fixes it or why sleep was causing the issue would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the comments:

> You’re using time.sleep. This will block the thread. You want to use
> await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time). - @dirn (this is the answer)

> However, having taken your comment and applied it in my code the
> results are a lot more consistent . So what is the difference between
> time.sleep in a worker and await asyncio.sleep.......I was thinking
> that each worker would get a separate request, so a sleep blocking
> that thread wouldn't affect the other - . @Chris Doyle

While I had not checked how uvunicorn sets up its workers by default, the whole point of using async for coding is doing everything - or as much as possible - on *the same thread*.
Since your views are defined as `async` that is specially true - this coding paradigm do not expect async functions to block when waiting for any call - the thread will be stopped.

If instead of `sleep` you have to call some code that will take time, and is not async ready, then you can make that call asynchronous by running the delegate function into a separate thread. Python asyncio makes that easy by providing the [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) call: it will automatically create a thread-based executor with a thread pool, and run your blocking function in a separate thread, while freeing up the current thread for the async event loop to further orchestrate other tasks/workers.

Otherwise, as said, if you are using `sleep` for test purposes, just await for `asyncio.sleep` instead.  You can use `await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 5)` to check how it would behave with a blocking function.